# Is there a faster way to count values across multiple columns, excluding duplicated values on the same row?

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following `df`

```
   id val1 val2 val3
0   1    A    A    B
1   1    A    B    B
2   1    B    C  NaN
3   1  NaN    B    D
4   2    A    D  NaN
```

I would like to sum the value counts within each `id` group for all columns; however, I need to only count values that appear on the same row once, so the expected output is:

```
id   
1   B    4
    A    2
    C    1
    D    1
2   A    1
    D    1
```

I can accomplish this with

```
import pandas as pd
df.set_index('id').apply(lambda x: list(set(x)), axis=1).apply(pd.Series).stack().groupby(level=0).value_counts()
```

but the `apply(...axis=1)` (and perhaps `apply(pd.Series)`) really kills the performance on large `DataFrames`. Since I have a small number of columns, I guess I could just check for all pairwise  duplicates, replace one with `np.NaN` and then just use `df.set_index('id').stack().groupby(level=0).value_counts()` but that doesn't seem like the right approach when the number of columns get large.

Any ideas on a faster way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the missing steps that remove row duplicates from your dataframe:

```
nodups = df.stack().reset_index(level=0).drop_duplicates()
nodups = nodups.set_index(['level_0', nodups.index]).unstack()
nodups.columns = nodups.columns.levels[1]
#        id  val1  val2  val3
#level_0                     
#0        1     A  None     B
#1        1     A     B  None
#2        1     B     C  None
#3        1  None     B     D
#4        2     A     D  None
```

Now you can follow with:

```
nodups.set_index('id').stack().groupby(level=0).value_counts()
```

Perhaps you can further optimize the code.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `get_dummies`

```
s=df.set_index('id',append=True).stack().str.get_dummies().sum(level=[0,1]).gt(0).sum(level=1).stack().astype(int)
s[s.gt(0)]
Out[234]: 
id   
1   A    2
    B    4
    C    1
    D    1
2   A    1
    D    1
dtype: int32
```

Comment: This is a nice compact way to do things for a small number of values. Sadly, I could have like 150,000 unique values in the columns, so I probably don't want to `get_dummies()`. Still far faster than what I had though!